# Velocity is already loaded - Materialize yeoman

Tags: angularjs, bower, yeoman, materialize

I installed with yeoman, materialize and angular-materialize by bower, but in the console browser appear this:

```
    Velocity is already loaded. You may be needlessly importing Velocity again;
 note that Materialize includes Velocity.
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I had a double import of `materialize.js`.

So when I removed the second one, the warning disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

It is due to double import by yeoman and bower. Use only one import.